# Run R codes on a cluster

Tags: r, bash, cluster-computing, executable

I use R to run some C codes (R Wrapper) that are very intensive. In consequence, I would like to run my .R file on a cluster. I used to run executables from C codes on the cluster with a .pbs file that looks like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
    #PBS -l procs=1
    #PBS -l walltime=240:00:00
    #PBS -N Name
    #PBS -m ea
    #PBS -M name@something.com
    #PBS -l pmem=1000mb
    #PBS -t 1-3
    echo "Starting run at: `date`"
    path/to/myscript
    echo "Job finished with exit code $? at: `date`"
```

Can I make an executable with my .R file and run it just as I did with my compiled C code? How can I compile my .R file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you're going to use your script under Linux/UNIX OS. If this is the case, add a `#! /usr/bin/env Rscript` shebang in your R script and make it executable `chmod u+x path/to/myscript`. You don't need to compile your code.

Please note that you might need to add something like `module load R` in your PBS script to load R environment variables.